# How can I generate dynamic LESS stylesheets?

Tags: less

I want to import a variables less file that is DB generated into to be used by my other less files. This will provide some high level variables for my app. What is the best way to import these? I've tried something like `@import "http://server.com/foo.less"` without success.

The file would look like:

```
@fontColor: #EEE;
@fontSize: 10px;
```

Generated from

```
@fontColor: {{fontColor}}
@fontSize: {{fontSize}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this using the url() "function"

```
@import url("http://localhost/foo.less");
```

This will import your less file at **compile time**, which slows down the process depending on how fast your request is being answered.
After that, all **variables** in this file will be available to your current scope.
Very likely, this applies to **mixins** as well, but I did not test that.

Answer (score 2):

With Asp.net your server could dynamic generate the less file. But I think it is also possible with other techniques.

HomeController

```
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult StyleMeFromCshtml()
    {
        Response.ContentType = "text/css";
        return View(new StyleModel());
    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>test less</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="/Home/StyleMeFromCshtml" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/less-1.4.2.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="styleMeLess">
        I'm styled
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

StyleModel.cs

```
public class StyleModel
    {
        public string BackgroundColor
        {
            get
            {
                // or get the value from the DB
                var random = new Random();
                var toArgb = Color.FromArgb(random.Next(256), random.Next(256), random.Next(256));
                return toArgb.Name.Remove(6, 2);
            }
         }
    }
```

The StyleMeFromCshtml.cshtml is less camouflaged in cshtml

```
@model lessTest.Models.StyleModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

.styleMeLess{
    background-color: #@Model.BackgroundColor
}
```

With every call of the index a random color is generated on the Server. But the color value could also come from the DB. The trick is that in the response the contentType is set "text/css".

Or you return the less string directly:

```
        public ActionResult StyleMe()
        {
            var random = new Random();
            var toArgb = Color.FromArgb(random.Next(256), random.Next(256), random.Next(256));
            string style = String.Format(".styleMeLess{{ background-color: #{0} }}",     toArgb.Name.Remove(6,2));
            return Content(style, "text/css");
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to `server.com` to get the file (and I assume you do), and that your path is correct (and I assume it is), it would appear to me that one error that needs corrected is that the file should look like (note the addition of the colons):

```
@fontColor: #EEE;
@fontSize: 10px;
```

I don't know if that means you need to change your generating code to:

```
@fontColor: {{fontColor}}
@fontSize: {{fontSize}}
```

I'm not familiar enough with what the double brackets means `{{...}}`, but I assume that is how the database is pulling information from it to put into the `.less` file that it is being generated. If so, then adding the colons there should resolve what LESS is expecting a variable to be defined like, and may solve your issue.

Comment: This is not what i'm looking for. I'm not having issues with generating less files, I want to be able to import a server generated less file in my setup.

Comment: @arturnt: Perhaps you need to clarify your question. I've reread it and I think what you are asking for is how you can import a server generated less file by another less file that is _not_ on that server? Is that correct? If so, I suspect that is not possible (though I have not verified that yet).

Comment: that is exactly what i'm asking :). It can be on the same server, but not served off the local filesystem.